# How can I correctly update a component's MaxHeight based upon dynamic content?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, accordion, use-effect, react-functional-component

I've created a React (functional) Accordion component that has its contents fed in through the parent. The code is as follows:

```
import React, {useEffect, useRef, useState} from 'react';
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome';
import { faChevronUp, faTrashAlt } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';
import './Accordion.css';

const Accordion = ({title, content, active}) => {
    const [isActive, setIsActive] = useState(active);
    const [expanderStyle, setExpanderstyle] = useState({maxHeight: 0});
    const contentDiv = useRef();

    useEffect(() => {
        setExpanderstyle(isActive ? {maxHeight: contentDiv.current.scrollHeight + 1} : {maxHeight: 0});
    }, [isActive]);

    const toggle = () => {
        setIsActive(!isActive);
    }
    
    return (
        <div className="accordion">
            <div className="accordion-title">
                <div>
                    <button className="btn btn-icon round small" onClick={toggle}><FontAwesomeIcon icon={faChevronUp} className={`icon rotator ${isActive ? "active" : ""}`}/></button>
                </div>
                <div className="accordion-title--title">
                    {title}
                </div>
            </div>
            <div ref={contentDiv} className="accordion-content" style={expanderStyle}>
                {content}
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

export default Accordion;
```

And I have set the styling for my `.accordion-content` as follows

```
.accordion-content {
    ...
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: max-height 0.4s linear;
}
```

Which creates a sliding animation for when the user expands / collapses the accordion.

The issue I'm facing is that, since the content is fed in through the parent, if I add in anything that changes the height of the accordion, the height doesn't get updated automatically.

Obviously, I could change the `max-height` to a large number to show everything, but, then, the animation effect changes dramatically, so I do need to calculate the content's height correctly.

I tried updating my `useEffect` to include `content` or `contentDiv` as part of its dependencies, but it seems the `useEffect` fires too soon and still doesn't size correctly.

How can I fix this?

Comment: The problem with adding the `content` to the `useEffect` dependencies is probably that the `useEffect` gets called before the DOM is updated. So adding a `setTimeout` with 0 duration could do the trick.

Comment: @Alimo, I tried, but it still didn't render correctly. For whatever reason the `scrollHeight` isn't the full value - As if it is a value from the middle of the render. Could it have to do with buttons / images being rendered, maybe?

Comment: If you are adding images dynamically, that might be the problem. You could try setting the height of the image statically so even if the image is not loaded, the `scrollHeight` returns the correct value.